# How to distribute X piece to N different thing in every possible way?

Tags: c#, combinations

Sorry for my bad english.
My problem is the following:
I need to distribute X piece between N things in every possible way.
Lets say the X is 5 and the N is 2 (but it can be anything else too for example 4, which is more complicated). 
It would be only for int so I tried a List< int[] > for result a result list, but I couldnt figure it out, how to generate the possible combinations.

For an input like X=5, N=2 my expected output would be:

1. {5, 0}
2. {4, 1}
3. {3, 2}
4. {2, 3}
5. {4, 1}
6. {0, 5}

Comment: Gotta post some code of what you've tried so far and what is not working. This is not a school assignment service.

Comment: Please specify what you have tried. What works and what doesn't. Please be specific about the environment you're in and tools you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You have initial sum X and N array cells.

Make a function.

If array is filled, output its contents.

Fill the first cell with all possible values.

For every value v call the function with `(X-v)` argument to fill the next cell.

If you are using global array, care about restoring of array state after recursive calls